# Writing inventory systems using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there anything (warnings, advices) that I should know if I want to develop an **inventory management system using Ruby on Rails**. The biggest problem that I could think of is on how to do long calculations on the stocks. The other one would be on how to do cachings on stock counts. BTW, I'll be using MySQL as the database. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is no reason for not writing it with Rails.
To the caching of stock count's, there is a method in Rails, which is named cache_column. This caches the number of relations in a column.
And to do big calculations on stocks. I don't know why this should be a problem.
And if this would da heavy work, you can put it into a worker.

Answer (score 1):

there is no argument that speaks against using Ruby on Rails for that.
if you want to make big calculations on a database level (like SUM) be sure to use BIGINT explicitely in your migrations for this column, as the MySQL Integer (signed) supports a Maximum of 2147483647, and the result of your calculation will be computed in the same data type by MySQL.

To keep track of cached stock counts, use [counter_cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)